# How to store user input and use it later in another function?

Tags: javascript, html, function, user-input

HTML:

```html
<div class="button" >
    <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" onclick="userInput()">
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.button{
    width: 75%;
    margin-top:5px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.button input{
    width: 80px;
    height: 30px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

JS:

```js
let email 
function userInput( ) {
    email = document.getElementById('submit').value 
    return email
}
console.log(userInput())
```

I want to store user input so that i can use it in another function. I do not understand why when I `console.log` the function or the variable `email` outside the function I get `undefined` on the console instead of the input entered by user.

Comment: Just access `document.getElementById('inputEmail').value` in the function directly. Or pass it as an argument when calling it.

Comment: "_i get undefined_". Providing `#inputEmail` exists, it's not possible to get `undefined`. You'll get an empty string from the function when calling it before user has entered text to  `#inputEmail`.

Comment: Your code works as it is, just read the value from `email` variable where you need it (after user has clicked the button), don't invoke the function.

Comment: Make sure that `#inputEmail` exists.